# Android: playing many short media files

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool

I am wring a program to play with about 1000 short media files which are stored in "raw". My programe is simple. It plays a new media file each time a button is clicked. The name of media file is read from an array list and I am using MediaPlayer

Here is my code when a button is clicked (only one button):

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    i++;
    String fileName=soundArray.get(i);
    int soundID=getResources().getIdentifier(fileName, "raw", getPackageName());
    if(soundID>0){
         MediaPlayer mySound=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),soundID);
         mySound.start();
    }
}
```

This code works fine with first two or three button clickings. After that, it is crashed. Do you think there is a problem with my code and should I use SoundPool in my case?

Comment: you code maybe not complete, you should fix you code, i think it miss loop control :)

Comment: We can't judge whether it will crash without the loop. At this point your code seems fine

Comment: What do you guys mean by loop control?

Answer (score 0):

use prepare() before starting the mediaplayer

```
mySound.prepare();
```

Comment: It is still crashed after playing 1 or 2 sounds

Comment: please paste your logcat report

Comment: `D/AndroidRuntime(1841): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(1841): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
E/AndroidRuntime(1841): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1841): java.lang.NullPointerException
...`